# Ruby - Calling setters from within an object

Tags: ruby

I've been working through the Pragmatic Programmers  'Programming Ruby' book and was wondering if it was possible to call a setter method within a class rather than just assigning to the instance variable directly.

```
class BookInStock

  attr_reader :isbn, :price

  def initialize (isbn, price)
    @isbn = isbn
    @price = Float(price)
  end

  def price_in_cents
    Integer(price*100 + 0.5)
  end

  def price_in_cents=(cents)
    @price = cents/100.0
  end

  def price=(dollars)
    price = dollars if dollars > 0
  end

end
```

In this case I am using a setter to ensure that the price can't be negative. What i want to know is if it is possible to call the price setter from within the price_in_cents setter so that I wont have to write extra code to ensure that the price will be positive.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course you can. Just try it. In Ruby, amazingly, you can even define methods inside other methods :-)

Answer (score 13):

Use `self.setter`, ie:

```
def price_in_cents=(cents)
    self.price = cents/100.0
end
```

Comment: why do you need self. with methods that are setters whereas you dont need to call self with other instance methods

Comment: Because `foo = bar` is variable assignment, not a method call. There are other cases as well: `+ foo` is `foo.+@`, not `self + foo`, for example.