# model attributes get visuality variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :ensure_login_has_a_value

  validates :login, :email, presence: true

  protected
    def ensure_login_has_a_value
      if login.nil?
        self.login = email unless email.blank?
      end
    end
end
```

Why it works but

```
protected
  def ensure_login_has_a_value
    if login.nil?
      #self.login = email unless email.blank?
      # the change  
      login = email unless email.blank?
    end
  end
```

does not work??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603633/anti-private-property-of-setter-method

Comment: not sure what issue you are having but you could change to this for such a simple method `before_validation {|user| user.login = user.email unless user.email.blank?}`

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715254/ruby-calling-setters-from-within-an-object

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699687/when-to-use-self-foo-instead-of-foo-in-ruby-methods

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297161/ruby-self-keyword

Answer (score 1):

In the second one,

```
  login = email unless email.blank?
```

Is creating a local variable call `login` and assigning it `email`

The first one actually assigns it to the  attribute of the model.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using `login` - it uses the getter, provided by ActveRecord, and if you would like to use `login=` you should declare login as `attr_accessible`